# Determine which of two tkinter canvas items is above the other

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Is there a way to determine which item is topmost on the displaying order of a `tkinter` canvas given their respective id's?

Comment: I didn't check it but I think last one should be the topmost. I think it keep on list to draw from first to last - so last is topmost, and it may search the same list from first to last - so last is topmost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `canvas.find_all()` to get all the item IDs and according to the [document](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M49): *"The items are returned in stacking order, with the lowest item first"*.

Below is an example to find the topmost item in a check list:

```py
check_ids = [1, 3, 5, 7]
all_ids = list(canvas.find_all())
# remove item IDs in all_ids that are not in check_ids
for x in all_ids[:]:
    if x not in check_ids:
        all_ids.remove(x)
# now all_ids contains only ID from check_ids sorted by stacking order
# so the last item ID is the topmost item in the list
topmost = all_ids[-1]
print(topmost)
```